# How to create a regex that will find a string, replace and put html tags before and after the values

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have this string in a javascript code:

`checker_securite: #    status: SUCCESS<br>sles_checker: #    status: SUCCESS#timeStamp: Mon Jun 27 2016 15:54:45 GMT-0000 (UTC)#vmName: LTROVRO100#changeNumber: CHG0061513#srId: SR0377578#menAndMice: #    status: SUCCESS#    ip: #        ag: 10.15.28.38#NouvelleVM: #    status: SUCCESS#cpuAndRam: #    status: SUCCESS#    cpu: 1#    ram: 1#extraDisk: #    status: SUCCESS#attributes: #    status: SUCCESS#cfEngine: #    status: SUCCESS#keytab: #    status: FAIL#`

I want to transform this string, in a human readable format, with indentation in html.

So I decided to go with a Definition list, `<DT>` will replace `#`, and `<DD>` will replace `#(4 spaces)`

But I need to place the closing tag. For example, how can a regex search trough this string and replace `#vmName: LTROVRO100#` with this:
`<DT>vmName: LTROVRO100</DT>`

But the ending `#`, is actually for the next string not ending this one. I could change the code that generate this and put 2 pound signs, but I thought that I could do somehting with a regex instead of adapting all the code.

Here's the end result:

`checker_securite: <DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DT>sles_checker:</DT><DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DT>timeStamp: Mon Jun 27 2016 15:54:45 GMT-0000 (UTC)</DT><DT>vmName: LTROVRO100</DT><DT>changeNumber: CHG0061513</DT><DT>srId: SR0377578</DT><DT>menAndMice: </DT><DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DD>ip:</DD><DD>ag: 10.15.28.38</DD><DT>NouvelleVM: </DT><DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DT>cpuAndRam: </DT><DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DD>cpu: 1</DD><DD>ram: 1</DD><DT>extraDisk: </DT><DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DT>attributes: </DT><DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DT>cfEngine: </DT><DD>status: SUCCESS</DD><DT>keytab: </DT><DD>status: FAIL</DD>`

Comment: Could you clarify how the result should look like and where should the HTML tags be? You can use ``` to format it as code and then you would be able to write html tags `<html></html>` Or you could simply put it on a new line and indent 4 spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution!

`var txt = msg.replace(/(#\s{4})(.*?)(?=#)/g,"$1<dd>$2</dd>");
var txt2 = txt.replace(/(#{1})(\w.*?)(?=#)/g,"$1<dt>$2</dt>");
msg = txt2.replace(/#/g,"");`